# gradle: aggregating multiproject testReport with some test disabled

Tags: build, gradle, automated-tests

I want to aggregate the testreports on my multiproject build. I have a project structure where I have disabled some tests. I have already looked at the [gradle sample code](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#subProjectsTestReport), which works fine with default settings, but as soon as I **disable the test task** on a subproject it stops working. (It looks for the testresult/*.bin file which is obviously not there..)
My project layout looks like this:

```
root 
 +--- ProjectA
 |    \--- ProjectA.gradle
 +--- ProjectB
 |    \--- ProjectB.gradle
 \--- build.gradle
```

ProjectA.gradle looks like this:

```
test {
   enabled = false
}
```

The rootprojects build.gradle has the testReport task.

As I said before the task fails on ProjectA. I tried to modify the sample code like this:

```
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
    reportOn subprojects*.test.findAll { test ->
        test.getEnabled()
    }
}
```

Still not works because test.enabled is true when the task executes.

How can I make this task work?

Answer (score 0):

> It looks for the testresult/*.bin file which is obviously not there

Probably worth a bug report at http://forums.gradle.org.

> Still not works because test.enabled is true when the task executes.

In fact it's `false` when the `testReport` task executes, but it's `true` when it gets configured. (Gradle has distinct configuration and execution phases.) This is because by default, parent project build scripts get evaluated before child project build scripts. One way to solve this problem is to move the declaration of the `testReport` task to the bottom of the parent build script and add an `evaluationDependsOnChildren()` just before that.

Comment: Thank you! I created a topic about this at the Gradle Forums: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/aggregating_multiproject_testreport_with_some_test_disabled